# Different definitions of profunctors

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory, profunctors

In [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor) a profunctor from category $\mathbb{C}$ to category $\mathbb{D}$ is defined to be a functor $\mathbb{D}^{\text{op}} \times \mathbb{C} \overset{F}{\rightarrow} \textbf{Set}.$ However in [Fong and Spivak (Definition 4.2)](http://math.mit.edu/%7Edspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf) a profunctor from category $\mathbb{C}$ to category $\mathbb{D}$ is defined to be a functor $\mathbb{C}^{\text{op}} \times \mathbb{D} \overset{G}{\rightarrow} \textbf{Set}.$ I would like to know which of these definitions is most common (especially for discussing the category of profunctors), and I would like to know how to convert between "profunctors" defined according to these two different definitions.

Comment: Converting seems quite trivial. An nlab-profunctor from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ is exactly a Fong/Spivak profunctor from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I suggest to look at classical references (neither nlab nor Fong-Spivak counts as classical) from the 60s/70s.

Comment: I believe that the nlab definition is and ought to be the standard one. It has the advantage that a functor $F:\mathbb C\to\mathbb D$ induces a profunctor from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb D$ (namely $(d,c)\mapsto\text{Hom}_{\mathbb D}(d,F(c))$), rather than the other way around.

Comment: @AndreasBlass But regardless of the definition chosen, every functor induces two profunctors, one in each direction (with the second one being $(c,d)\mapsto\text{Hom}_{\mathbb D}(F(c),d)$).

Comment: @ArnaudD. with the nlab convention you get an inclusion functor $Cat \to Prof$ whereas with the other convention you get an inclusion $Cat^{co} \to Prof$ where $Cat^{co}$ is obtained from $Cat$ by inverting the direction of 2-cells